# android adb no permissions for device

Tags: android, linux, adb, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running on

```
$ uname -a
Linux mpolak-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-3 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I've downloaded Android studio 2023.1.1.28 which installed adb tool in $HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/

```
$ ls -l $HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mpolak mpolak 7885616 jan 31 10:13 /home/mpolak/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.5-10900879
Installed as /home/mpolak/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
Running on Linux 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
```

I connected my "android" device and run

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
JC8B00010383    no permissions (missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

So I followed the recommended steps from the link

1. `sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME`
2. logout, login
3. `apt-get install android-sdk-platform-tools-common`

Verified by

```
$ groups
mpolak adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

```
$ id
uid=1000(mpolak) gid=1000(mpolak) groups=1000(mpolak),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),135(lxd),136(sambashare)
```

But this doesn't helped, so I started looking on web.

There is recommendation to create rules file for the device, so I

1. printed and identified my usb device

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 1e0e:9031 Qualcomm
```

2. created `51-android.rules` file and changed mode `sudo chmod 644 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

```
$ ls -l /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12747 feb  1 17:19 /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

and inserted
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1e0e", ATTR{idProduct}=="9031", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0666"`

3. `$ sudo service udev restart`
4. `$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`
5. disconnected usb cable from device
6. `$ adb kill-server`, `$ adb start-server`
7. connected usb cable to device
8. but no device available after running

```
$ adb devices 
List of devices attached
```

Is there problem with permissions for the 51-android.rules file, or is the rule wrong or what I'm missing?

I also tried to run the server with sudo, but the result is the same

Setting `$ ADB_TRACE=all`

With record rule in 51-android.rules

```
$ adb devices 
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Version 34.0.5-10900879
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Installed as /home/mpolak/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Running on Linux 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:160 _adb_connect: host:version
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:107 writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
02-01 17:37:35.893 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:194 _adb_connect: return fd 3
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
List of devices attached
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:400 adb_query: host:devices
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:358 adb_connect: service: host:devices
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:160 _adb_connect: host:devices
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:107 writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a64657669636573 000chost:devices
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:194 _adb_connect: return fd 3
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:376 adb_connect: return fd 3
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303030 0000
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=0
02-01 17:37:35.894 53597 53597 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=0 got=0
```

Commenting out the record rule from 51-android.rules

```
$ adb devices
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Version 34.0.5-10900879
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Installed as /home/mpolak/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 Running on Linux 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_trace.cpp:187 
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:160 _adb_connect: host:version
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:107 writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:194 _adb_connect: return fd 3
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
List of devices attached
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:400 adb_query: host:devices
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:358 adb_connect: service: host:devices
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:160 _adb_connect: host:devices
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:107 writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a64657669636573 000chost:devices
02-01 17:39:30.029 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:194 _adb_connect: return fd 3
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_client.cpp:376 adb_connect: return fd 3
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=4
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303835 0085
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:81 readx: fd=3 wanted=133
02-01 17:39:30.030 53755 53755 D adb     : adb_io.cpp:97 readx: fd=3 wanted=133 got=133 4a4338423030303130333833096e6f20 JC8B00010383.no  [truncated]
JC8B00010383    no permissions (missing udev rules? user is in the plugdev group); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your udev rules are conflicting with the plugdev group requirement. One possibility is that you might have other configurations under /lib/udev/rules.d
Alternatively, you could examine effective configurations by using the following utility to iterate over your usb devices:
$ udevadm info --attribute-walk -n /dev/bus/usb/001/028 | grep 'Qualcomm'